# c# Parsing string containing HTML special chars as XElement

Tags: c#, gwt, special-characters, xelement

Using .NET c# on the server + GWT on the client side, I have a web form which takes user input which I then construct an XML string from and store it in the database. I then need to read it back from the database, send it to a hand held device over tcp and parse it as an XElement. All works well until you copy and paste text from word or excel in which case when I try to do:

```
XElement.parse(str);
```

It throws an exception:

```
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 132, position 111.
```

Example character that would cause this issue is right apostrophe char (0x2019). Now there can be a whole load of special chars possibly copy-pasted from excel/word etc. What is the best way to handle this? Here is how I construct the string from the stream:

```
protected CallResult callUsingSocketClass(string methodName, params Action<CallParameters>[] addParameters)
```

{
            WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_ENTRY_EXIT, "++Call({0}, ...)", methodName);

```
        if (this.OnTransferring != null)
        {
            if (!this.OnTransferring())
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        CallParameters parameters = new CallParameters(this, methodName);
        foreach (var addParameter in addParameters)
        {
            addParameter(parameters);
        }

        string post = this.CreatePost(parameters);
        WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC(Method={0}, host={1}, port={2}, post='{3}')", methodName, this.Host, this.Port, post);
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post);

        //
        // Send the request and wait for the reply.
        //
        char[] replyContentChars = null;
        for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 3; attempts++)
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            try
            {
                WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC - creating socket for RPC call...");
                if (this.OnTransferring != null)
                {
                    if (!this.OnTransferring())
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                string hostID = this.Host;
                if (this.HostIPAddress != null)
                {
                    hostID = this.HostIPAddress;
                }
                using (socket = this.connectToServer(hostID, this.Port))
                {
                    if (socket == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    if (this.OnTransferring != null)
                    {
                        if (!this.OnTransferring())
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC - socket created!");
                    WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC - communicating with server...");
                    WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC - writing post...");
                    this.sendDataToServer(socket, postBytes);
                    int replyLength = -1;
                    if (this.OnTransferring != null)
                    {
                        if (!this.OnTransferring())
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC - reading reply...");
                    using (var reader = this.receiveStreamFromServer(socket))
                    {
                        if (this.OnTransferring != null)
                        {
                            if (!this.OnTransferring())
                            {
                                socket.Close();
                                socket = null;
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                        for (; ; )
                        {
                            string lineRaw = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
                            string line = lineRaw.ToLowerInvariant();
                            if (line.StartsWith("content-length:"))
                            {
                                replyLength = int.Parse(line.Substring(15));
                            }
                            else if (line == "")
                            {
                                if (replyLength < 0)
                                {
                                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Reply hasn't specified content-length");
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (this.CookieJar != null)
                                {
                                    this.CookieJar.ProcessFromServer(lineRaw);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Content starts here
                        replyContentChars = new char[replyLength];
                        int replyRecv = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            int charsRecv = reader.Read(replyContentChars, replyRecv, replyLength - replyRecv);
                            if (charsRecv <= 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            replyRecv += charsRecv;
                        } while (replyRecv < replyLength);
                        //int charsRecv = reader.Read(replyContentChars, 0, replyLength);
                        if (replyRecv != replyLength)
                        {
                            untime.Logger.Logger.Error("Web Service call '{0}' received {1} bytes, header indicated {2} bytes", methodName, replyRecv, replyLength);
                            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Have not received all of reply data - received {0} bytes, expected {1}", replyRecv, replyLength));
                        }
                    }
                    socket.Close();
                    socket = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC - exception thrown - {0} [{1},{2}]", e.Message, e.Source, e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (socket != null)
                {
                    socket.Close();
                    socket = null;
                }
            }
            if (replyContentChars != null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (this.OnTransferring != null)
            {
                if (!this.OnTransferring())
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        //
        // Verify that data has been received.
        //
        if (replyContentChars == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (this.OnTransferring != null)
        {
            if (!this.OnTransferring())
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        //
        // Process the received data.
        //
        string replyContent = new string(replyContentChars);
        WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC(Method={0}, replyContent='{1}')", methodName, replyContent);

        XElement xReplyContent = XElement.Parse(replyContent);

        var xReplyBody = xReplyContent.Element(nsSoap + "Body");
        var xFault = xReplyBody.Element(nsSoap + "Fault");
        if (xFault != null)
        {
            // Something has gone wrong on the server
            var xFaultCode = xFault.Element(nsSoap + "Code");
            var xFaultReason = xFault.Element(nsSoap + "Reason");
            untime.Logger.Logger.Error("Web Service call to method '{0}' failed: Code='{1}', Reason='{2}'", methodName, (string)xFaultCode, (string)xFaultReason);
            string faultCode = (string)xFaultCode;
            var codeParts = faultCode.Split(':');
            XmlQualifiedName xmlQualifiedName;
            if (codeParts.Length == 2)
            {
                xmlQualifiedName = new XmlQualifiedName(codeParts[1], codeParts[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                xmlQualifiedName = new XmlQualifiedName(faultCode);
            }
            throw new SoapException((string)xFaultReason, xmlQualifiedName);
        }

        var xResponse = xReplyBody.Element(this.nsArgs + (methodName + "Response"));
        var xResult = xResponse.Element(this.nsArgs + (methodName + "Result"));
        if (this.OnTransferring != null)
        {
            if (!this.OnTransferring())
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        var result = new CallResult(xResult);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The code is not complete. Where is `replyLength` defined? You got an endless `for` loop in the example.

Comment: ok i have pasted the method that does the work here now. from line 70 onwards you can see how i build the string.

Comment: what output do you get from `WebServicesClient.Debug.DebugMessage(WebServicesClient.Debug.MASK_RPC_CALL, "RPC(Method={0}, replyContent='{1}')", methodName, replyContent);`

Comment: jgauffin, I have found the answer. Please see below. thanks

Comment: It will work for regular ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` since it looks like Excel uses utf. convert to your favorite encoding.

Comment: Tried it ... still got the same issue

Comment: How do you get the `str` variable?

Comment: The string actually get sent to a hand held device. Where it is read from the stream as UTF8 and then converted to string using the UTF8

Comment: I mean how do you get the string in code? How do you built it from the stream?

Comment: Can't paste all the code as the characters are limited but here is a summary: I read from the tcp stream using (var reader = new StreamReader(tcpStream, Encoding.UTF8, false)) and populate the data into a char[] . then I do string replyContent = new string(replyContentChars);

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to the issue here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/54c83f23-e579-48e9-9fbe-bc20232a02fc/

The idea is either to strip/replace unicode characters from the input or use a unicode encoding in the XML when constructing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

In the above post the accepted answer suggests the following method (pasting here) which works fine but if you need to replace certain characters, you would have to add some code to do that in addition:

```
      public string getRidOfUnprintablesAndUnicode ( string inpString )   
    {   
        string outputs = String.Empty;   
        for ( int jj = 0; jj < inpString.Length; jj++ )   
        {   
            char ch = inpString[ jj ];   
            if ( ( ( int )( byte )ch ) >= 32 & ( ( int )( byte )ch ) <= 128 )   
            {   
                outputs += ch;   
            }   
        }   
        return outputs;   
    }
```